# Read from a Pipe

Tags: c, pipe

I need to read the total result from a C PIPE. I could just create a massive buffer and slowly fill it, but that seems inefficient and very memory hungry, so I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas how to do it.

Here is my code:

```
FILE* pipe = popen(command, "r");
if (!pipe)
{
    strcpy("FAIL", output);
    return -1;
}

char buffer[128];

while (!feof(pipe))
{
    if (fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != NULL)
    {
        // should add buffer to main one here
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

In C++ I could just add it to a String, but I'm not sure how I'd do that in C.

**Edit** : I don't know the size of the final buffer.

Comment: What's the question exactly? What's wrong with what you're doing?

Comment: I need to put the whole results from the program in one buffer.

Comment: have you looked into `realloc()`?

Comment: @hexa & @TomMan - realloc is very inefficient, and even more memory hungry: you're keeping the original buffer while allocating the new one (i.e.: you're having two buffers at some point allocated at once), and you copy the data around all the time (worst case, of course). So performance-wise there's no benefit vs pre-allocating all the memory at once, on the contrary.

Comment: @TomMan - do you know the size of data ahead of time?

Comment: @littleadv define inefficient. What you say is that realloc may be performance inefficient (maybe the buffer needs to be reallocated somewhere) but it IS memory efficient, since you are guaranteed to get only as much memory as you need.

Comment: @hexa, you're right on that distinction, but I was assuming that the amount of memory needed is known ahead of time, which maybe incorrect. I asked for clarifications from @TomMan on that. If the amount of memory needed is not known - then realloc is indeed a good option.

Comment: `realloc` does not necessarily keep the old buffer and then allocate a new one. It may just make the existing buffer bigger. Whether it does depends on a bunch of things, such as what else is in memory, and where.

Comment: @littleadv it's not only a good option, it is also a safer option. If you just assume "it will fit" without really checking it, you might run into stack smash and etc

Comment: @hexa - well, don't assume anything about my programming skills, checking boundaries is trivial enough not to be mentioned every time we discuss memory allocations:-) Put your response about `realloc` as an answer.

Comment: @Lars - that's why I wrote "worst case". I'm a pessimistic person by nature :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *I could just create a massive buffer and slowly fill it, but that
>   seems inefficient and very memory
>   hungry*

If you need everything to be in the memory - that's the only way to go. You can cache interim results in a temporary file, if it takes long time to gather all the data together, but eventually you'll have to have that huge memory buffer filled one way or another. The interim caching can be either at the sender side or the receiver, up to you.

I'm not sure I can follow your dilemma...

**edit**

After some clarification it appears that the problem is that the amount of the needed memory is not known ahead of time.

For that `realloc` is indeed one of the ways to handle, using a file as the interim caching method will take care of that as well without the additional memory performance hit that `realloc` causes (but instead you get a time performance hit because disk I/O is much slower).

Comment: The problem is that I could create a big buffer, which could be much bigger than necessary which may use up too much memory.

Comment: @TomMan - now your problem is clearer, so I edited my answer.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, I probably should have said that at the beginning.

Comment: Ok, I think I've worked it out by using realloc. From testing it seems to work fine, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You could start with a fairly low buffer size and then double it whenever you run out of space. This should keep buffer size within a reasonable bound but won't take a huge number of reallocations. (I gathered from comments that you don't know the necessary size ahead of time.) I would say that `realloc` is a fairly safe bet and with this method you'll only call it a few times.